# Writing a vector of floating numbers to a string. TypeError: not enough arguments. Python

Tags: python

I want to write a vector of floating numbers to a string. Part of my code is:

```
str_to_print = """
Tracking_ROI_X = %s
Tracking_ROI_Y = %s
"""

ROI_X_vect = [1272.0, 8.0, 8.0, 1272.0]
ROI_Y_vect = [1016.0, 1016.0, 8.0, 8.0]

str_to_print = str_to_print %(','.join(str(j) for j in ROI_X_vect))
str_to_print = str_to_print %(','.join(str(j) for j in ROI_Y_vect))

% OUTPUT, should be:
Tracking_ROI_X = [1272.0, 8.0, 8.0, 1272.0]
Tracking_ROI_Y_vect = [1016.0, 1016.0, 8.0, 8.0]
```

I am getting an error called TypeError, but I do not understand why? what could be the solution for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the format (`%`) operator, you need to provide replacements for **all** the `%s` etc. placeholders in it. You can't do it one-by-one in multiple calls the way you do it.

The correct way is:

```
str_to_print = str_to_print % (','.join(str(j) for j in ROI_X_vect),
                               ','.join(str(j) for j in ROI_Y_vect))
```

Answer (score 2):

Your format string has two placeholders, but you're only passing one string. That's not how string interpolation works, you'll have to pass everything at once:

Do:

```
print str_to_print % (
    (','.join(str(j) for j in ROI_X_vect)),
    (','.join(str(j) for j in ROI_Y_vect)) 
)
```

Note that this won't give exactly what you want. Your format string should have the `[`and `]`.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you need two replacements in your `str_to_print` string you must put it in the same line:

```
>>> str_to_print = str_to_print %(','.join(str(j) for j in ROI_X_vect), ','.join(str(j) for j in ROI_Y_vect))
>>> print str_to_print

 Tracking_ROI_X = 1272.0,8.0,8.0,1272.0
 Tracking_ROI_Y = 1016.0,1016.0,8.0,8.0
```

By the way, it is recommended using `.format` instead of `%`, taken from Python documentation:

> This method of string formatting is the new standard in Python 3, and should be preferred to the % formatting described in String Formatting Operations in new code.

So you may want to change your code to:

```
str_to_print = """
Tracking_ROI_X = {0}
Tracking_ROI_Y = {1}
"""

ROI_X_vect = [1272.0, 8.0, 8.0, 1272.0]
ROI_Y_vect = [1016.0, 1016.0, 8.0, 8.0]

str_to_print = str_to_print.format(','.join(str(j) for j in ROI_X_vect), ','.join(str(j) for j in ROI_Y_vect))
```